# Convert 12hr Time String to DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

So I'm processing some raw XML and it has a time element with a value as such

10:30PM

or conversely

10:30AM

etc etc

The Date is presumed to be today...

If I was to use DateTime.TryParse; would anyone be willing to help out crafting a FormatProvider would to do the job?

It doesn't have to be DateTime.TryParse if anyone else has a smarter solution..

Comment: `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` is what you want here.

Comment: The only smart solution is to use parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a custom format provider - you just need to specify a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with the [AM/PM designator specifier ("tt")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier):

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed to: {0}", result);
}
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. I'll check that out. Would I need to add the result of that to DateTime.Today?

Comment: @daveL: IIRC, it defaults to today - but I would personally make that explicit for clarity. (Add `result.TimeOfDay` to `DateTime.Today`.)

Comment: Jon, thanks for your help. 4 out of 6 values parsed perfectly.. however these were all PM times; the two AM times failed to parse - I think it may have been because the time string was '8:15AM' and not '08:15AM'... would my suspicion be correct?

Comment: @daveL: In that case, you should specify `h:mmtt` instead of `hh:mmtt`.

Comment: Yep... that's what I presumed. I've created an extension that will do it all inline for the two cases. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is it possible to parse that as US Eastern Time... we are in BST and it's being parsed as local time?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and make sure about format like `hh`for 12 hrs and `HH` for 24Hrs, same for minute `MM` for month and `mm` for minute. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more custom options :

```
string strTime = "10:30AM";
DateTime dtTime;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strTime, "hh:mmtt",  
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtTime))
 {
    Console.WriteLine(dtTime);
 }
```